# Power BI - Setting Waterfall graph

Tags: graph, powerbi, waterfall

I'm trying to create a personalized waterfall graph on Power BI, but I can't get the results I expected.
I have this data sheet. In Excel it's easy to set the waterfall graph with the 'Define as Total' tool.
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYVkm.png)

This is the graph I want to create on Power BI (This one I made on Excel:
[Waterfall graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGEyq.png)

But on Power BI I'm getting this result:
[Result on Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdfwM.png)

What I need is the 'Total' and 'Total + Hedge' columns set as a total column, just like the example graph on Excel.
Is this possible? I have to change the data sheet?

Comment: Have a look here at the paragraph at the bottom: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-waterfall-charts?tabs=powerbi-desktop  … the **Breakdown** bucket might provide you with a work around if you can re-arrange your data and table structure to that logic aka “hierarchy” … good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Cannot use Waterfall visual as you have two total bars. One solution is use Stacked Column visual with assist column of value:

[image]

Table data should be:

[image]

But color cannot be changed I am afraid.